# Extended search presets in grid panel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs, netzke

What is required to save extended search presets work?

When I click on Save in Search window, popup say Preset successfully saved. I see parameters passed to savePreset method,  but presets are missing after page reload.

I am looking at the Netzke demo app, but cannot figure it out. I've created tables netzke_component_states, netzke_preferences. Nothing is saved in the tables after preset save.

I am using Netzke 0.6 branch with Ext 3.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out. Adding netzke-persistence gem has solved the problem.

In Gemfile:

`gem 'netzke-persistence', :git => "https://github.com/skozlov/netzke-persistence.git"`